# A regex that validates a web address and matches an empty string?

Tags: regex

The current expression validates a web address (HTTP), how do I change it so that an empty string also matches?

```
(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Comment: It didn't occur to me from your question that you were matching lines in a text file... I thought you were likely parsing the html of an http-response for links within and couldn't figure out the context of your 'empty string' goal until I read the answer you selected.  Think different, eh?

Comment: in case it's helpful to anyone browsing in as I did, the best match string I've architected for URLs buried within HTML is "((http)s?:\/\/)([\w\.\-_]*(\/)?)*(#[\w\.\-_])?" -- I tested it against multiple popular sites with many links each, and it will also encompass the end-of-URL page-class-search tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expression markers `^$` around your expression and add `|^$` to the end. This way you're using the `|` `or` operator with two expressions showing that you have two different match cases.

```
^(https?:\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)$|^$
```

The key here is that `|^$` means "or match blank".

Also, that expression with only work in javascript if you use a template string.

Comment: Thanks, although I no longer need this, I like your answer!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to modify the expression to match *either* an entirely empty string **or** a full URL, you will need to use the anchor metacharacters ^ and $ (which match the beginning and end of a line respectively).

```
^(|https?:\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)$
```

As dirkgently pointed out, you can simplify your match for the protocol a little, so I've included that for you too.

Though, if you are using this expression from within a program  or script, it may be simpler for you to use the languages own means of checking if the input is empty.

```
// in no particular language...
if input.length > 0 then
    if input matches <regex> then
        input is a URL
    else
        input is invalid
else
    input is empty
```

Comment: Accepted as the answer because you were the only person to mention the ^ and $ required, without which simply adding the ? made any pattern match.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put the whole expression in parenthesis and mark it as optional (“`?`” quantifier, no or one repetition)

```
((http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)?
```

Answer (score 0):

`Expr?` where `Expr` is your URL matcher. Just like I would for `http` and `https`: `https?`. The `?` is a known as a Quantifier -- you can look it up. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

> ? The question mark indicates there is zero or one of the preceding element.

Comment: That's a great name DG, our world is a lesser place without DA in it.